# Redirecting from ReactJs page, Google Maps Navigation Rounding off the coordinates

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, navigation

For example, When redirecting from React App to
`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/0,0/0.3380065887,32.57799514` it is rounded off as `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/0,0/0.3380066,32.5779951/@10.6004811,17.4814272,3z/data=!3m1!4b1`.
The coordinates gets changes and points towards slightly wrong location.

Comment: If those are lat,long 6 decimal places gets within roughly 0.11 meters.  7 decimal places gives you centimeter accuracy.  So it begs the question, what are your accuracy requirements (in distance)?  In other words, what is "slightly wrong".  (Latitude dependent).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.